# Как запросить повышение прав пользователя?

Tags: windows

Утилита выполняется из под одного пользователя на Windows 7. В определенный момент требуется выполнение действий, для которых у текущего пользователя нет прав. Как запросить повышение привилегий? Нужно ли просить пользователя войти под другим аккаунтом?

Answer (score 3):

[UAC](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) устроен таким образом, что повышений привилегий возможно только для всего процесса и только при создании. Значит, если Вы хотите иметь возможность выполнить какое-то действие с повышенными привилегиями, запросив их «на ходу», Вам надо код, выполняющий эти действия, выделить в отдельный процесс.

Вообще, создание приложения, корректно работающего с UAC не так просто как кажется (как хотелось бы) ;). Главное — правильно обработать ситуацию, когда Вам не дали повысить привилегии. Ну и не забудьте, конечно же, что Вашу программу могут запустить под WinXP, где никакого UAC нет — программу придётся явно выполнять от имени другого пользователя.

Есть довольно [неплохая статья](http://pascalfonteneau.developpez.com/articles/delphi/vista/uac/VistaUACandDelphi.pdf). Там пример для Делфи — надеюсь, она Вам поможет.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно вынести действия, требующие повышения привилегий, в отдельный исполнимый файл. В манифесте этого файла надо указать, что ему требуется повышение. Утилита сможет его вызвать в нужный момент, и пользователь увидит стандартный UAC-запрос на повышение.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант поставьте проверку от какого пользователя запущено приложение.
Если выполняется от админа то продолжить, если нет вывести окно с просьбой запустить как надо.